# Submit form in background and use information in background

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

Basically my user inputs code. I can't check whether this code is valid or not(algorithm is a secret). Therefore I send(with form submit) this code to website that checks it (as `$_POST` variable). I have managed to do that. But how do I:

-Not display this webpage (user must stay on my webpage!)

 
-Get part of html from the website, that should not show and use it to fill variables (I know exactly which part of html I am looking for)

Can anyone point in the right direction with this problem..

Comment: Use Ajax (maybe jQuery) for sending the form. Use file_get_contents to get the html code from the remote website.

Comment: @icecub Alright. That's actually very helpful to me :D. Only thing I need to find out how to send form with ajax without showing it. Any idea on that, maybe quick fiddle?

Comment: Here's the fiddle you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/fun46f4f/

Comment: @icecub Alright thnx man, im looking into it

Comment: @icecub XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Any idea how to bypass this?

Comment: You can't. You're not allowed to make a XMLHttpRequest to a remote host because of the "same origin policy". Using CORS makes it possible to share data across domains, however all participating domains must use special response headers to make that work.

Comment: Anyway. It might be a whole lot easier if you just mail me your code so I can take a look at it for you. Mail can be found on my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a simple function to add an event handler for submition and a function for posts, if you use the preventDefault function for the submit event, the form's action doesn't get performed, i.e. the side doesn't get reloaded. the html code you want to receive has to be fetched on server side, and transmitted back to the client

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("example.com/somefile.php", sentData, function(receivedData){
        useTheResponseData(receivedData);
    });
});
```

Comment: alright trying it out. I will inform you how it goes :p